# Rails monkey patch only on certain columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to include a module only if the subclass has a certain column,
and I am doing this in an initializer:

```
 class ActiveRecord::Base
      def self.inherited(subclass)
        subclass.include(MultiTenancy) if subclass.new.respond_to?(:tenant_id)
      end
    end
```

I keep getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the module that I am importing:

```
module MultiTenancy
  class TenantNotSetError < StandardError ; end

  def self.included(model)
    model.class_eval do
      belongs_to :tenant
      validates :tenant_id, presence: true
      default_scope -> {
        raise TenantNotSetError.new unless Tenant.current_tenant
        where(tenant_id: Tenant.current_tenant.id)
      }

      def multi_tenanted?
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong. I can include the module on any subclass separate eg. `Klass.include(MultiTenancy)` successfully, so the problem is with the initializer.

Below is the stack trace:

```
from -e:1:in `<main>'2.1.1 :002 > Klass.all
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:9:in `relation_delegate_class'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:112:in `relation_class_for'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:106:in `create'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:133:in `table_name='
    from /home/lee/Code/mobifit/app/models/klass.rb:25:in `<class:Klass>'
    from /home/lee/Code/mobifit/app/models/klass.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):2
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/lee/Code/mobifit/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/lee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.1.1 :003 >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the stack trace back a bit, you can see that the thing that's `nil` that isn't supposed to be is is the class's `@relation_delegate_cache`. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb), you can see that this normally gets initialized in the `initialize_relation_delegate_cache` method, which is called in the `inherited` hook for `ActiveRecord::Delegation::DelegateCache`.

`ActiveRecord::Base` extends this module, so normally a class that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` would call this inherited hook. So the problem with your code is that you're monkey-patching `inherited` on `ActiveRecord::Base`, which means that the hook in `ActiveRecord::Delegation::DelegateCache` is no longer being called.

Two comments:

1. This is why it's a bad idea to monkey-patch, especially something as fundamental and complex as active record. Is it possible to do what you want to do in a more straightforward way?
2. If it's not, you should take some notes on how `ActiveRecord::Delegation::DelegateCache` works and rewrite your monkey patch to mix in a module of your own, rather than just over-writing `ActiveRecord::Base`'s `inherited` method.

The suggestion in (2) would look something like this:

```
module MultitenancyConcern

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.include(MultiTenancy) if subclass.column_names.include?("tenant_id")
    super #this is critical for avoiding the error you're getting
  end

end
```

then your monkey-patch becomes just

```
ActiveRecord::Base.extend(MultitenancyConcern)
```

Comment: I have updated my question to show more code, I get the same error if I just do `subclass.include(MultiTenancy)`, so it is not the constructor

Comment: In that case more of the stack trace is needed to figure out what's going wrong. Just knowing that *something* is nil that's supposed to respond to `:[]` isn't enough.

Comment: OK I added the stack trace